# How to download base64 to pdf in react native

Tags: android, react-native

i want to download **pdf** file from **base64** string. I want to do it without using fetch, because i will fetch the data before then i want to download it.

Comment: Where is that base64 string to begin with?

Comment: i am fetching base64 using `graphQL` api,, then i want to download it using download button click

Comment: `Where is that base64 string to begin with? ` Please just answer this question. Or tell where it all begins.  For instance where that pdf file is.We dont know what you are doing. Explain!

Comment: i am explaining :- first i upload pdf as base64 using `graphql` query to database ,, then i get this base64 from the database in another screen ,,here i added an download button,,so i want to download this base64 to pdf in download folder

Comment: So your base64 encoded file is on a server somewhere and then you download that base64 encoded file and if you have downloaded that base64 string you will decode it to a pdf file and save that pdf file to Download folder. All these steps?

Comment: Please put what you want in your post! Write a good post to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

try the package [fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob). At first download your base64 data then save it as file into device storage. You can get asset uri from fetch-blob and show it.

```
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    fileCache : true,
    // by adding this option, the temp files will have a file extension
    appendExt : 'png'
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // the temp file path with file extension `png`
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
    // Beware that when using a file path as Image source on Android,
    // you must prepend "file://"" before the file path
    imageView = <Image source={{ uri : Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + res.path()  : '' + res.path() }}/>
  })
```

i hope it will be helpful.